# How to change web2py connection timeout on pythonanywhere?

Tags: web2py, pythonanywhere

I am hosting a web2py application on PythonAnywhere. My problem is that the application is bound to take few minutes to respond(because of data processing or non-optimized implementation). During this time the page times out.
I get a message from PythonAnywhere that something went wrong and my application is taking more time than usual.
I want the framework to wait until the web2py function finishes(even if it takes minutes). Is it a setting I need to change in web2py or is it something that I need to change in PythonAnywhere?

Thanks and Regards!

Comment: You should post this issue in the pythonanywhere forum as well. They usually answer fast and they are always very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have a good general solution for this. Our timeout is pretty long (3 minutes, I think). In general it's not a good idea to keep your users waiting with a loading page for minutes because they're going to assume that something went wrong. Your best bet is probably to break the big task into smaller chunks and do each of the chunks in a separate request, then you can show your users a progress meter that updates as each request completes.